# How can I get a device name from within a IoT Edge Custom module (python)

Tags: python, azure-iot-edge

**SUMMARY**

I don't get the expected hostname from the device when requesting it via python code; I get some container ID

**BACKGROUND**

When running the following code on Raspbian in python 3:

```
import socket
print(socket.gethostname())
```

or:

```
import platform
platform.node()
```

...you get the hostname of the machine you're running the code on.
(That's what I expect)

When doing the same from a Custom IoT Edge module you get some kind of identifier for I think the container?

How can you get the hostname of the system the container is running on within the container module itself?

**SOLUTION**

As suggested the Device ID and Module ID are exposed as environment variables:
IOTEDGE_DEVICEID and IOTEDGE_MODULEID.

So now in python you can do the following:

```
DEVICEID = os.environ["IOTEDGE_DEVICEID"]
MODULEID = os.environ["IOTEDGE_MODULEID"]
```

And then use the variables like that in your (python) code down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/986#issuecomment-475257607) for a similar question. Short answer: do a `docker inspect` on your custom module container and see the different environment variables that are available. One of them is the hostname of your Edge device.

Comment: This was exacty what I was looking for! I didn't find the Github page before.  
I now do the following in python in the code for my custom module:    `DEVICEID = os.environ["IOTEDGE_DEVICEID"]`  `MODULEID = os.environ["IOTEDGE_MODULEID"]`  and then I can perfectly use them further down the line. :-)